# Pet bonus from Mogdrogen's Pact doesn't show on pet bonuses?

Tags: grim-dawn

On my skill tree under the Mogdrogen's Pact, I have listed "bonus to all pets: 106% physical damage".
But on the character window under pet bonuses, damage have a 0% displayed.

The skill is active and the pet (Briarthorn) is near.

What's going on?
Another thing is that the skill adds 26% to the pets life bonus, but this time it IS listed on the character window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character sheet only has a single damage value listed for pets - their "+% to All Damage" multiplier:

[image: screenshot showing pet +% damage, but no damage-type specific values]

This means there's no field on your character sheet to show damage bonuses that are limited to a specific damage type, like the +% Physical Damage from Mogdrogen's Pact.  Similarly, you won't see the +% Vitality Damage from [Mythical Spirit Cannon](https://www.grimtools.com/db/items/8747).  Only +% to All Damage (like from Occultist's Manipulation node, or the [Subjugator's prefix](https://www.grimtools.com/db/prefixes/3124)) will show up in your pet stats on your character sheet.

Contrast with the section for your own character's damage, where each damage type is listed separately:

[image: screenshot showing +% damage for your character, with separate numbers for each damage type]

Bonuses to individual damage types apply to any damage of the appropriate type that's dealt by your pets (so the +% Physical Damage from Mogdrogen's Pact will apply to your Briarthorn's Physical damage, but not its Bleeding damage, since that's a separate type).  They just don't show up properly on your character sheet, since it has nowhere to display them.

Comment: Thats kind weird, theres no such thing as plain damage right? so I tough the damage under pet bonuses would be all the damages, but instead it only shows the 'all damage' bonuses? Did I get it right? Its like they made a design mistake..

Comment: There is no untyped damage, no.  The reason pets have their "+% to All Damage" stat listed is that *most* bonuses to pet damage are All Damage bonuses; bonuses to specific damage types like Mogdrogen's Pact are fairly rare for pets.  As for why they didn't bother to include fields for individual damage types, who knows?  Wanted to save space or something.  I agree it'd be nice to be able to see it on the character sheet.